# SonarQube 5.4 svn lines of commit

Tags: svn, numbers, sonarqube, commit, sonarqube-web

In SonarQube 5.4 is it possible to get the number of commits per user from the svn and who introduced the violation.

Comment: I have no information on SonarQube, but from the svn side you can look at the `svn blame` command to determine who last edited the problem lines.

Answer (score 0):

Number of commits per user - no. Not currently.

Who introduced an issue - with high probability*. New issues will automatically be assigned to the last committer on the relevant line.

* Note that the last committer on the line where the issue is raised is not always the one responsible for the issue.